# Как замостить пространство(блок) div-ами?

Tags: css, css3, html, позиционирование

Нужно пространство `.diamond-parent` замостить блоками `.diamond`.
Как вариант, можно сделать png-картинку и замостить бекграундом, но интересно решение через CSS.

```css
.diamond-parent {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background: lightpink;
}

.diamond {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border: 30px solid transparent;
  border-bottom-color: red;
  position: relative;
  top: -30px;
}

.diamond:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: -30px;
  top: 30px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border: 30px solid transparent;
  border-top-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="diamond-parent">
  <div class="diamond"></div>
  <div class="diamond"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно это сделать с помощью двух градиентов:

```css
body {
  background-color: lightpink;
  background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, red 25%, transparent 0, transparent 75%, red 0), 
    linear-gradient(-45deg, red 25%, transparent 0, transparent 75%, red 0);
  /* указываем размеры "ячейки" */
  background-size:60px 60px;
}
```

#### Небольшая заметка:

Я использую `0` как ступенях градиентов, чтобы не дублировать предыдущие значения, так как по [спецификации](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-images/#color-stop-syntax) ступенька градиента не может быть меньше предыдущего значения.

> If a color-stop has a position that is less than the specified position of any color-stop before it in the list, set its position to be equal to the largest specified position of any color-stop before it.

Answer (score 0):

Говорили про `png`, но про `svg` никто не говорил=)))

```css
body{
  background: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='15' height='15'><rect transform='rotate(45)' y='-5.6126599' x='5.6126599' height='11.22532' width='11.22532' id='rect3598' style='fill:#ff0000;'/></svg>")  repeat lightpink;
  height: 400px;

}
```